# Application update did not change UI

Tags: android, package-managers, in-app-update

We have in-app update feature were we use `installPackage()` of `PackageManager` to install new update of the app.

This is working most of the time. But at times we're facing an issue were app version is change but App UI & code is not. I can see that App version updated from the API request but UI didn't change and API request are same as old version.

```
public UpdateManager(Context context) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {

        observer = new PackageInstallObserver();
        pm = context.getPackageManager();

        Class<?>[] types = new Class[]{Uri.class, IPackageInstallObserver.class, int.class, String.class};
        method = pm.getClass().getMethod("installPackage", types);
    }

public void installPackage(File apkFile) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        if (!apkFile.exists()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        Uri packageURI = Uri.fromFile(apkFile);
        installPackage(packageURI);
    }

public void installPackage(Uri apkFile) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        method.invoke(pm, new Object[]{apkFile, observer, INSTALL_REPLACE_EXISTING, null});
    }
```

This app has system permissions (INSTALL_PACKAGES).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you change your **Manifest** ?